# How to detect if an iframe has been dynamically added to page

Tags: jquery, iframe, load

I need help with how to detect if an iframe has been dynamically added to page. I thought I could do it by listening out for the load event:

> ```
> jQuery(document).on("load","iframe",function(){
> console.log("an iframe has been added");
> })
> ```

but that doesn't fire.

Comment: Is it a typo? You never finished console.log

Comment: How are you adding the iframe(s)?

Comment: The iframe can turn up in variety of ways on the page... the user can add a module that contains one while editing pages, and than it can be displayed in various other locations. The content of the iframe comes from one domain (and can have no js in it) and is displayed on another domain. I'm wanting the parent page to detect whenever the iframe is loaded so I can change its dimensions and manipulate an element inside it. ... (typo fixed, ta)

Answer (score 0):

You can poll to see if an iframe is being added as it could be added after your document loads e.g.

```
var orig = $("iframe").length;//Set this to 0 if you don't expect any
var iframeDetect = setInterval(function () {
    if($("iframe").length > orig) {
        console.log("Iframe added");
        clearInterval(iframeDetect);
    }
}, 500);//Every half a sec
```

Paste it into your dev tool's console, add an iframe to the page and look back at your console to test it.

Comment: Clever idea... but waiting 1/2sec will be too long sometimes. I might have multiple iframes loaded that require manipulation to display correctly, so this might look glitchy.

Comment: You can change the time to make it lower e.g 100 is a tenth of a sec and run the test once to before the setInterval just to be sure.